# How to convert ints to specific byte sizes and then combine to send on a socket

Tags: python, tcp

I'm sending 5 numbers over a TCP socket.
The first number that I'm sending needs to be 4 bytes long.

I'm looking for a way to convert all the data I'm sending into bytes and then send it as one packet.

Here's 3 attempts that I've tried, not all are successful. By "unsuccessful" I mean that the client hangs - no response is seen from the server.

Attempt 1: unsuccesful

```
packet_part_1 = uid.to_bytes(4, 'little')
packet_part_2 = bytearray([action, context, payload_length, payload])

packet = bytearray(packet_part_1)
packet.extend(packet_part_2)

s.send(packet)
```

Attempt 2: successful

```
packet = [0, 0, 0, uid, action, context, payload_length, payload]
s.sendall(bytes(packet))
```

While successful, deliberately padding the first number with 0's is a cheat that won't allow for larger numbers, so isn't really practical.

Attempt 3: unsuccessful

```
packet_part_1 = uid.to_bytes(4, 'little')
s.sendall(packet_part_1)

packet_part_2 = [action, context, payload_length, payload]
s.sendall(bytes(packet_part_2))
```

Attempt 4: unsuccesful

```
packet_part_1 = uid.to_bytes(4, 'little')
s.sendall(packet_part_1)

packet_part_2 = [action, context, payload_length, payload]
for i in range(0, len(packet_part_2)):
    s.sendall(packet_part_2[i].to_bytes(1, 'big'))
```

This could be because the server is expecting the data in a different format - all at once (like in attempt 2) vs. the splitting up like in Attempts 1, 3, and 4

Ideally, I can combine all the data such that I can send with one `sendall()`. But I can't figure out how to do that. Attempts 1, 3, and 4 were ways to circumvent that.

Thanks for any help you can provide!

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64362290/python-struct-pack-and-unpack

Comment: Your problem is exactly the kind of problems [struct.pack](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html) was designed to tackle, i.e. `struct.pack('LLLLL', ...)` for 5x 4 byte unsigned int.